# C# Windows Universal 10 TopMost Window

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app

I'm developing a Windows 10 Universal app (`UWP`).

Is it possible to set application as TopMost (always on top)? Like `WPF` or `Winforms` (TopMost property).

Thanks

Comment: No, there is no concept of TopMost in UWP. (What would it mean for a phone app to be topmost?)

Comment: Thanks for answer, UWP can also runs in PC, I want this option for PC not phone.

Comment: The U in UWP stands for Universal. Note that there is no concept of TopMost on the PC in tablet mode either. (In tablet mode, there are no overlapping windows.)

Comment: @RaymondChen: UWP apps running on phones and tablets don't have the concept of a title bar. Therefore, titlebar should not exist for Desktop right? I'm sorry but your understanding of "universal" is flawed.

Comment: @disklosr The lack of a title bar doesn't impair functionality, because the title bar is external to the app. The app can ask for a red title bar, and if there's no title bar, well you could say that the invisible title bar is red if you like. But if an app set the "Go topmost" flag, and it doesn't actually go topmost, then the app looks broken.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A feature called CompactOverlay mode was added in the Creators Update that supports this type of functionality. When an app window enters compact overlay mode it’ll be shown above other windows so it won’t get blocked. This allows users to continue to keep an eye on your app's content even when they are working with something else. The canonical example of an app taking advantage of this feature is a media player or a video chat app.

A blog post describing the feature can be found here

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/universal-windows-app-model/2017/02/11/compactoverlay-mode-aka-picture-in-picture/

Comment: The link to the blog post in galactic.fungus comment has gone. Anyone know where to find it or similar?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is **no**, there is no way **as of today** to make the application modal.

There is a [petition going](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/11179821-uwp-windows-always-on-top) around asking for this functionality, which was requested last December but given the amount of votes it got (35 at the time this answer was written), it doesn't look like it will be taken into consideration anytime soon.

As mentioned in the comments, this functionality would be PC only so even if it was added, my assumption would be that it wouldn't work outside of the PC mode (so no tablet, mobile or surface family device support).

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible UWP apps have some restrictions compared with WPF of Win32 apps(classic apps).

With uwp apps you need enable some capabilities to do something special in your app as you can see in the link uwp apps need ask for permission or they can't access or modify files directly.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt270968.aspx

Best Regards