# Put the calculator on TopMost C#

Tags: c#, windows, api

I am doing an app which will launch for example MS Word, MS Powerpoint,
 notepad and calculator.
 So to do that I used the SetWindowPos API and it works for all except the calculator
 do you have an idea why ? 
Here is what I did :

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, uint windowStyle);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

private void LaunchOnTop(string processPath)
{
    Process process = new Process();

    process.StartInfo.FileName = processPath;
    process.Start();
    process.WaitForInputIdle();

    if (process != null)
    {
        ShowWindow(process.MainWindowHandle, 1u);
        SetWindowPos(process.MainWindowHandle, new IntPtr(-1), 0, 0, 0, 0, 3u);                
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Windows?

Comment: @Tatsu You can't. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35596356